# Is a travel insurance necessary when transiting through Prague?

Tags: insurance, czech-republic

Because of price, instead of taking a flight to Berlin, I have had a flight to Prague booked, and will take a bus to Germany. I am aware that a travel insurance is necessary as a tourist in Czech Republic, or I will have to pay a fine, but is that also the case for entering the country? As far as I am aware we will not be staying in Prague; our time in Czech Republic will be 5 hours or less.

Comment: Whether a legal requirement or not, you should never travel without a basic travel insurance.

Comment: @JonathanReez by visa national do you mean I require a visa to enter Schengen? In that case no, I am South Korean.

Comment: Yes if you're a South Korean you are not a visa national.